# Is it possible to use the GoogleApiClient in an Android app without Google+ sign in?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-plus, google-play-services, facebook-android-sdk

My Android app has maps and location updates involved. The location updates in particular require a `GoogleApiClient` instance:

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(service.getGoogleApiClient(), locationRequest, this);
```

I'd like to offer both Google+ and Facebook as login options and have built that out. But on testing the Facebook login, I've noticed by `GoogleApiClient` instance is not connected. If I try to connect it, it'll fail with `SIGN_IN_REQUIRED`.

That `SIGN_IN_REQUIRED` to me implies user interaction along the lines of a Google+ login. Is it possible to use the Google Play Services stuff like location updates without the user having logged in using Google+?

Comment: To my knowledge Google Play Services does not rely on Google+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It entirely depends on what APIs you have added to your `GoogleApiClient` via [addApi](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.Builder.html#addApi(com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api%3CO%3E,%20O)) - if you include an API that requires login (such as [Plus.API](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/Plus.html#API), then yes, you will need the user to sign in. If however, you only include APIs that do *not* require login (such as [LocationServices.API](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationServices.html#API)), then no login will be required.

Note: you are **not** limited to only a single `GoogleApiClient` - if you'd like to maintain one for `Plus.API` and another for `LocationServices.API`, you can certainly do exactly that.

Comment: Thanks. Have split by GoogleApiClient instance out into two, as you suggested, and this seems to work fine.